# Not able to Archive in Xcode 9

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode9, ipa

Hello friends I am using MAC OS X High Sierra on Oracle V M Virtual Box and have been trying to archive and make the .IPA file and have followed several steps but not able to achieve it can anyone help me how i can do it

Comment: This could happen for lots of reasons. Telling us what machine your running and telling us that it fails doesn't give us enough information to help you. You must at least of had some error?. have you checked the build logs?

Comment: there are lots of error i get like . i cannot create a provisioning profile . unable to create certificate . unable to connect my iphone to my mac via virtualbox . not able to add development team . facing a lot of problem from last 3 days and have tried almost every other solution from google finally i came here to ask

Comment: Without provisionig profile how can you create .ipa file. First learn how to create Provisioning profile with Adhoc for .ipa

Comment: Sorry, but how did you think we was going to guess all of that information? you **cannot** archive without a provisioning profile so please update your question to be about creating provisioning profile issue. You are not supposed to be able to use virtualbox for iOS development, so that is a whole other issue that is technically unsupported

Comment: So u r saying i can't achieve it using virtual box for iOS development ??

Comment: I am saying that Apple do not like you doing that or support it, you probably can do it but I dont know how to do it. your main problem is the provisioning profile. without that it doesn't matter what you do... you will not archive.

Comment: whenever i add development team it gives me 2 errors : cannot be registered to your development team and other is couldn't find any iOS development provisioning profiles matching my files

Comment: Ok @Scriptable thank you so much for your response and your information ..